# Traveling from USA to Canada

Tags: usa, trains, canada, driving, ships

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada

https://www.google.com/search?q=world+map+with+country+name&oq=World+map&aqs=chrome.3.0i271j69i57j0i433j0j0i433.7270j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=MjGDMLXc3-faOM

https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=isch&sxsrf=ALeKk00CjpAiLFk0z_BU5B5m5TOc3J6Z4w%3A1609474247033&source=hp&ei=x6DuX7Ei1oLj4Q_e_ZyYDQ&q=usa+to+canada+map&oq=USA+to+Canada&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQARgBMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BwgjEOoCECc6BAgjECc6CAgAELEDEIMBOgUIABCxAzoECAAQA1DgF1jzWWC2aWgBcAB4AIABnQOIAbsQkgEKMC4xMS4xLjAuMZgBAKABAbABBQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img#imgrc=6MyXY6lelPNDAM

Other than Air travel from USA to Canada & vice versa from any city source to any city destination, are there also the following transportation modes even if they are taking more time?

1 Road - Buses, Car etc

2 Train

3 Ship

Examples :

Washington DC to Ottawa

New York to Toronto

Case study :

Point A (Source) - President Trump's, Official administration, White House, Washington DC,USA.

Point B (Destination) - Prime minister Justin's Official administration, Ottawa, Canada.

Instead of Chartered plane or Helicopter, official of White House would like to meet Official of Prime Minister Justin by Train, Car or Ship for trade discussions.

Train mode of transport : How much time and what is the exact route?

Car mode of transport : How much time and what is the exact route?

Ship mode of transport : How much time and what is the exact route?

Thanks & Regards,

Prashant S Akerkar

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question would improve a lot when you replace those links with short lines of text, explaining what is in the link and then hide the link (or just add the text and one of the other users will do the hiding for you.) And edit in the information you added in the comment on the answer.

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: you are not making this question better with that edit. Also, we are not travel agents.

Comment: do you just want to know how to get from Washington, DC, USA to Ottawa, Ontario, Canada by train or by car? (Traveling between those two locations by ship is slightly insane.)

Comment: I also think there are better tools (typically Google Maps itinerary) for finding an exact route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking your question at face value:

Yes, there are extensive road,  rail and bus connections between USA and Canada. There are very many road crossing points on the 8,891km land border between the two countries which allow private cars to cross, and rental cars depending on rental agreements.

Buses and trains run across the border between most major cities, and many towns close to the border. Check the timetables with either Amtrak or VIA Rail, Greyhound or other bus companies, or Google for them. Bus and rail connections certainly exist between your example cities. Be aware that they can take ten hours or more.

Ships are a rare and specialized form of transport between two countries with a massive land border, but East of Montreal you can find ferries that cross between the countries.

Comment: Thank you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada%E2%80%93United_States_border As you mentioned "Ships are a rare and specialized form of transportation between both the countries", How much time will it take for traveling by Ship from US city to Canada city & vice versa?

Comment: Thanks. I would also like to know how many halts will be there between US city & Canada city & vice versa by Ship with the harbour / port names.

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar I guess you'll have to search that yourself, Google will help you a lot

Comment: There is also a ferry between Seattle and Vancouver. https://www.clippervacations.com/seattle-victoria-ferry/ Currently suspended because of Covid

Comment: Thanks Hilmar. I feel i got the answer. Washington DC - Seattle (Road) - Ship - Vancouver - Ottawa (Road).

Comment: Thanks. I got the train route. https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Ottawa/Washington?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=question-stationquery-from-train#r/Train

Comment: Washington DC to Seattle is 4400km by road. That's a LONG drive.

Comment: "How much time will it take for traveling by Ship from US city to Canada city & vice versa?" That hugely depends on the cities. Boston to Vancouver? Weeks. Bar Harbor Maine to Yarmouth Nova Scotia? Couple of hours. Same for the number of stops. Except for a few ferry routes, travelling by ship between US and Canada is pointless.

Comment: If you are interested in how to get from Ottawa to Washington DC by private boat, then look up "Erie Canal". If you need a bigger boat then "St. Lawrence seaway".

Comment: Thanks for the information. https://www.google.com/search?q=st+lawrence+seaway&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=imnv&sxsrf=ALeKk01-BqyLdwyrOEhHnxj1ooHkaK2_Vw:1609557334567&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFpLCppPztAhVaxzgGHYlzBVAQ_AUoAXoECCEQAQ&biw=360&bih=592&dpr=2#imgrc=F04H8tqpcLa7oM